# How do you access HttpContext from within _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

Project: ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web application

I've added an object to the `HttpContext.Items` collection from within a controller and I am trying to access the object to hide some menu options in the `_Layout.cshtml`, but I am getting an error

> Object reference required

How do I set the reference?

```
@if (HttpContext.Items["CurrentUser"] == null) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are calling HttpContext as static like:

[image]

you could get the instance of HttpContext in View as below:

```
this.ViewContext.HttpContext
```

althougth you could get the httpcontext,It would also not work for your requirement.

You'd better try with ViewData/ViewBag

In Controller:

```
ViewData["Key"]=somevalue
```

In View:

```
@if(ViewData["Key"]==null){....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the `RazorPage` `Context` property:

`@if (Context.Items["CurrentUser"] == null) { }`